# ASP.NET Interchangeable Function

Tags: asp.net, function, modularity

Imagine I have two sites that share basic code.  Most of their code matches exactly, but a couple functions don't match.  For example, what if these two sites differed in the method they used for determining if the current user was using an acceptably new Web browser.  So isGoodBrowser() returns true or false, but the sites have a different version of this function.  How can I make this one function interchangeable while keeping the rest of the code the same?  I'd like to contain such a function in a file of its own.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you put the shared methods in a separate assembly?

Comment: If the code won't be the same and isn't reusable elsewhere, then *don't share it in the first place*.

Comment: What if in the constructor of the "Browser" object you have a property set by a variable passed that decides which site this browser belongs to and from there you make your isGoodBrowser() function do one thing or another?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make three assemblies:

1. Assembly containing all the code which **is** shared.
2. Assembly containing functionality specific to the **1st** web site.
3. Assembly containing functionality specific to the **2nd** web site.

Reference the common assembly from both web site projects.

You can even specify an interface for `isGoodBrowser()` in the shared assembly and implement it differently in site-specific assemblies. Then inject the appropriate implementation either manually, or via an IoC container, such as Unity.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out out to implement this.  I've tried making a BasicClass (which calls isGoodBrowser()), an IGoodBrowser interface which states its use of isGoodBrowser(), and a third interchangeable file with a varying definition of isGoodBrowser().  I've tried this setup, but BasicClass can't seem to access isGoodBrowser().

Comment: I didn't end up using your suggestion, but I wanted to check it as the best answer anyway since it makes sense to me.  Thank you.